# Fill Excel Workbook containing Data Validation dropdowns using Python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have Excel file containing dropdowns created with data validation.

In first sheet I add the avaible workers and later select them from the dropdowns in second worksheet created with data validation

#### Insert Workers

[image: Insert workers]

#### Select Workers from Dropdown

[image: Select workers from dropdown]

Now I want to add additional workers from my Django application.
I open the file and edit it with **openpyxl**

```py
import openpyxl
wb = openypy.load_workbook('/home/michal/Project.xlsx')
ws = wb['Workers']
ws['A8'].value = 'Eve'
wb.save('/home/michal/Project/saved.xlsx')
```

Doing that Im losing the ability to select values from dropdowns.

The reason is that **openpyxl** doesnt load the data connections between sheets.
Which we can see comparing xml included in the file.

*Original file*

```
    <mergeCells count="3">
        <mergeCell ref="A3:B3"/>
        <mergeCell ref="A13:B13"/>
        <mergeCell ref="A23:B23"/>
    </mergeCells>
    <pageMargins left="0.7" right="0.7" top="0.75" bottom="0.75" header="0.3" footer="0.3"/>
    <extLst>
        <ext uri="{CCE6A557-97BC-4b89-ADB6-D9C93CAAB3DF}"
             xmlns:x14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/main">
            <x14:dataValidations count="1" xmlns:xm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/excel/2006/main">
                <x14:dataValidation type="list" allowBlank="1" showInputMessage="1" showErrorMessage="1"
                                    xr:uid="{B93E0E6F-3CDC-46D6-AB87-8FB207C05210}">
                    <x14:formula1>
                        <xm:f>Workers!$A$2:$A$20</xm:f>
                    </x14:formula1>
                    <xm:sqref>B4:B8 B14:B18 B24:B28</xm:sqref>
                </x14:dataValidation>
            </x14:dataValidations>
        </ext>
    </extLst>
</worksheet>
```

*Edited with openpyxl*

```
    <mergeCells count="3">
        <mergeCell ref="A3:B3"/>
        <mergeCell ref="A13:B13"/>
        <mergeCell ref="A23:B23"/>
    </mergeCells>
    <pageMargins left="0.7" right="0.7" top="0.75" bottom="0.75" header="0.3" footer="0.3"/>
</worksheet>
```

Any changes in xlsx xml files result in file or worksheet being corrupted.

Is there a valid way of copping unchanged worksheet xmls between files, or do you know any library that is able to load full workbook having the *extLst* nodes.
I'm running this script from Django App on Ubuntu server and because of that can't use the xlwings.

Comment: `extLst` nodes contain extensions to the OOXML specificationa and are not supported by openpyxl.